# TinyMCE table not showing in editor

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE 4.6.0. When I add the table plugin and use it in toolbar, it doesn't show when I add it in the editor, The cursor does go down indicating activity, but nothing shows!

Comment: Perhaps you could use http://fiddle.tinymce.com/ to create an example of this happening using TinyMCE and your exact configuration?  Did you test in the latest TinyMCE (4.9.3 or 5.0.3)?  If its fixed there updating would be the solution.

Comment: Hi, It works on the fiddle so I will be looking to upgrade (which from my earlier experience, is not as trivial as replacing files). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 tinymce.init({
                    selector: '.textEditor',
                    plugins: "advlist lists table paste textcolor colorpicker tabfocus link preview",
                    toolbar: "table fontsizeselect bold italic underline forecolor backcolor bullist numlist link preview code", imagetools_toolbar: "rotateleft rotateright | flipv fliph | editimage",
                    menubar: false,
                    toolbar_items_size: 'large',
                    min_height: 500,
                    max_height: 800,
                    convert_newlines_to_brs: false,
                    statusbar: false,
                    relative_urls: false,
                    remove_script_host: false,
                    language: 'en',

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer to my original comment keep a few things in mind...

1. When you insert the table does the right HTML get placed in the editor?   If you enable the `code` plugin you should be able to see the HTML source that TinyMCE is trying to render.  If the HTML for the table is there then the plugin did its job.
2. Assuming the HTML is there you need to determine why it is not visible.  You have multiple ways to pass CSS into TinyMCE and that CSS will impact how things look in the editor.
3. Lastly, look at the configuration options for the `table` plugin itself.  There are some that impact how a table is visualized in the editor such as this one:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/plugins/table/#table_grid.

Comment: I have upgraded to 4.9.3 and the problem still persists. On inspection of the code, instead of inserting a table, it inserts paragraphs. I will enable the code plugin as well look at No 3 above. Thank you so much

Comment: I enabled code and the source code shows <br/>s and <p><p/>s when I insert a table.

Comment: Can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle that replicates this behavior?  This is not how the editor normally behaves so it likely has to do with your configuration or other custom code.

Comment: This replicates the behaviour

Comment: tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea',
menubar: false,
            plugins: [
             'link advlist lists anchor print preview insertdatetime paste table wordcount'
            ],
            toolbar: 'style-h3 | undo redo | bold italic strikethrough | link | bullist numlist | anchor | paste |  insertdatetime | table',
            branding: false,
            valid_elements: 'h3,a[href|target=_blank|target=_self],br,p,ul,ol,li',
            force_br_newlines: true,
            link_assume_external_targets: false,
            relative_urls : false
});

Comment: I think I have found why -> valid_elements: 'h3,a[href|target=_blank|target=_self],br,p,ul,ol,li', 

Thanks